# Convert C++ code to C# for encrypting algorithm

Tags: c#, c++, c

Look at this code

```
 h = (c >> 4) & 0xf;
 l = c & 0xf;
 printf(h + 'x');
```

How do I convert this code to C#?

Comment: Have you tried it "as is"?

Comment: It would probably help, if you have provided the types of h, c, l. Just saying. Other than this, all the operators exists in C# as well. Only printf needs to be replaced by Console.Write(..).

Comment: Why was the C tag removed? It's only C code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That printf is completely wrong, you are attempting to make a pointer from an integer without a cast and surely you don't want to cast the number to a const char*. Assuming it is meant to print the assumed unsigned integer. The equivalent is:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(120 + (c / 16));
```

or to be pedantic:

```
UInt32 h = (c >> 4) & 0xF;
System.Console.WriteLine('x' + h);
```

I would note that the bit-wise operations are unneeded, any decent compiler will do it for you.

```
UInt32 h = c / 16;
System.Console.WriteLine(120 + h);
```

The l variable is not even used in that code, but in C# it would be:

```
UInt32 l = c & 0xF;
```

Which is more nicely written as:

```
UInt32 l = c % 16;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 h = (c >> 4) & 0x0f;
 l = c & 0x0f;
 System.Console.WriteLine(h + "x");
```

That might work.

Comment: `h + "x"` in C# is different from `h + 'x'` in C and C++. In C# the character 'x' has to be converted to an integer, and then added to `h`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I don't think that's true.  But it certainly shouldn't be `+ "x"` either.  That would concatenate the string `"x"` to it, which isn't what the C++ does.  It should be `(char)(h + 'x')`, otherwise it will convert the character's value to an int, and print out the sum of the ints.

Comment: Ah, so he's shifting a char value by adding a number to it. Been a while since I've used printf(), I've forgotten the insanity having worked with C#'s strings. ^_^